# GAS to fill and submit a google form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I need a google form to load new data in to a google spreadsheet (not too hard).

I need the users to validate older data already in a spreadsheet.

My idea was to use the old data spreadsheet to fill the google form and populate the google form's spreadsheet.

I've found the Mogsdad's answer to [Kite's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410497/use-app-scripts-to-open-form-and-make-a-selection/20510224#20510224), and tryed the example....

It seems to work as you can see in the execution log:

```
[15-03-11 11:53:09:468 CET] Avvio dell'esecuzione
[15-03-11 11:53:09:853 CET] UrlFetchApp.fetch([https://docs.google.com/a/xxx.xxx.xxx/forms/d/1_Xvokasdfq1AtMJEEgIw-NKPVY9oEqorEY9-yGi-lvtTY/formResponse, {payload={entry.1075692923=Rossi, entry.1034411028=Mario}, method=post}]) [0,366 secondi]
[15-03-11 11:53:09:854 CET] HTTPResponse.getResponseCode() [0 secondi]
[15-03-11 11:53:09:855 CET] Esecuzione riuscita [0.369 secondi di esecuzione totale]
```

The http response is 200:successfully:

Logger.log("getResponseCode:" + response.getResponseCode() ); -->15-03-11 13:26:30:884 CET] getResponseCode:200.

but doesn't add any row to the spreadsheet!

whats wrong?

Thanks, Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the clue!!

Thanks to user1989's comment to the [Brian Frederickson's Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27137997/google-form-autosubmit-using-urlfetchapp-attempting-to-authenticate)...

The Google form need to be public!! Because UrlFetchApp doesn't pass any autentication!

Now i can read data from the input spreadsheet, pass through the google form to fill the output spreadsheet and let the user edit the single lines via google form!!!